# configuration for msysgit bash inside emacs on windows

Tags: emacs, msysgit

What do you add to your .emacs file to use msysgit bash inside emacs ? 
I just modified the cygwin instructions for msysgit replace cygwin with msysgit everywhere in these .  
The only thing i can't do is run ssh or vim inside the bash... 
directory completions work with windows style drive names prepended at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your "_emacs.el" - it works for me:

```
;; When running in Windows, we want to use an alternate shell so we
;; can be more unixy.
(setq shell-file-name "C:/Program Files/msysgit/bin/bash")
(setq explicit-shell-file-name shell-file-name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update May 2018: Git 2.18 (Q2 2018) has now removed the `contrib/emacs/` content.

> Users of the git.el mode are now much better off using either Magit or the Git backend for Emacs's own VC mode.

See "[Emacs Lisp error at `init`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50301261/6309)" for more.

---

Original answer 2011:

Not tested, but [the idea was (2008)](http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit/browse_thread/thread/b852fef689817707#m) to copy in your Git installation directory at least:

```
contrib\emacs\git.el    
contrib\emacs\git-mswin.el
```

With `git-mswin.el` being "[Windows/msysgit specific modifications for `git.el`](http://repo.or.cz/w/git/mingw/4msysgit.git/commitdiff/3c30e5e87358eba7b6d7dcd6301ae8438f0c30ea?hp=8f4e9dca13aba080505aa95897de2833b1f421d6)".