# Emacs Lisp error at init (file-error "Cannot open load file" "/home/user/a-m")

Tags: emacs, init

I've recently made a few changes in my init emacs file, and I've noticed with --debug-init that some load files seem to be missing. Here is the output from the debugger

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "/home/andre/a-m")

load("/home/andre/a-m" nil nil t)

load-file("a-m")

eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/default.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 269

load-with-code-conversion("/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/default.el" "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/default.el" t t)
load("default" t t)

#[0 "\205\262

command-line()

normal-top-level()
```

I've searched for what the a-m file stands for online, and how to correct these errors but without success. Thanks for any help!

Best
Andre

Edit: Here is the init file. I've just changed some info on jabber (email) but other than that the file is unchanged

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; File name: ` ~/.emacs '
;; ---------------------

;; If you need your own personal ~/.emacs
;; please make a copy of this file
;; an placein your changes and/or extension.

;; Copyright (c) 1997-2002 SuSE Gmbh Nuernberg, Germany.

;; Author: Werner Fink, <feedback@suse.de> 1997,98,99,2002

;; Test of Emacs derivates
;; -----------------------
(load-library "url-handlers")

;; Always use PDFLaTeX
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)

;; TeXcount setup for AUCTeX
(require 'tex)
(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
(list "TeXcount" "texcount %s.tex" 'TeX-run-command nil t))
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)`
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)

;; MELPA
(when (>= emacs-major-version 24)
  (require 'package)
  (add-to-list
   'package-archives
   '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
   t)
  (package-initialize))

;; YASNIPPETS
(add-to-list 'load-path
              "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
(setq yas-snippet-dirs
      '("~/.emacs.d/snippets"               ;; personal snippets
    "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet/snippets/"    ;; the default collection
        ))
(yas-global-mode 1) ;; or M-x yas-reload-all if you've started YASnippet already.

;; Timestamp controls
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'time-stamp)
(setq time-stamp-pattern nil)

;; Controls for calendar
(setq european-calendar-style t)
(set-default 'truncate-lines t)

;; Controls for jabber
(require 'jabber)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; TRAMP mode
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(setq tramp-default-method "ssh")

;;;;;;;;;;;
;;ORG mode
;;;;;;;;;;;

(define-key global-map "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(define-key global-map "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
(setq org-log-done t)
(setq org-agenda-files (list "~/org/NOTES.org"))
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic
      browse-url-generic-program "firefox")
(setq org-support-shift-select 't)
(setq org-agenda-include-diary t)
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)

;;;;;;;;;;;
;;G-CODE
;;;;;;;;;;;

(require 'generic-x)
(define-generic-mode gcode-generic-mode
  '(("(" . ")"))
  (apply 'append 
         (mapcar #'(lambda (s) (list (upcase s) (downcase s) (capitalize s)))
                 '("sub" "endsub" "if" "do" "while" "endwhile" "call" "endif" 
                   "sqrt" "return" "mod" "eq" "ne" "gt" "ge" "lt" "le" "and" 
                   "or" "xor" "atan" "abs" "acos" "asin" "cos" "exp" 
                   "fix" "fup" "round" "ln" "sin" "tan" "repeat" "endrepeat")))
  '(("\\(#<_?[A-Za-z0-9_]+>\\)" (1 font-lock-type-face))
    ("\\([NnGgMmFfSsTtOo]\\)" (1 font-lock-function-name-face))
    ("\\([XxYyZzAaBbCcUuVvWwIiJjKkPpQqRr]\\)" (1 font-lock-string-face))
    ("\\([\-+]?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+\\)" (1 font-lock-constant-face))
    ("\\(#[0-9]+\\)" (1 font-lock-type-face))
    ("\\([0-9]+\\)" (1 font-lock-constant-face)))
  '("\\.gcode\\'")
  nil
  "Generic mode for g-code files.")

;;;;;;;;;;;
;;OpenSCAD
;;;;;;;;;;;
(add-to-list 'load-path
         "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/")
(autoload 'scad-mode "scad-mode" "Activate OpenSCAD mode." 'interactive)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.scad\\'" . scad-mode))

;;;;;;;;
;;ANSYS
;;;;;;;;
     (add-to-list 'load-path
          "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/")

     (autoload 'ansys-mode "ansys-mode" "Activate Ansys mode." 'interactive)

    (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.txt\\'" . ansys-mode))
    (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.db\\'" . ansys-mode))
;    (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.dat\\'" . ansys-mode))
;    (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.inp\\'" . ansys-mode))

;;;;;;;;;;;
;;LS-DYNA
;;;;;;;;;;;
     (add-to-list 'load-path
          "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/")
      (autoload 'lsdyna-mode "lsdyna" "Enter ls-dyna mode." t)
      (setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.k\\'" . lsdyna-mode) auto-mode-alist))

;;;;;;;;;;;
;;ABAQUS
;;;;;;;;;;;
;; ;; setup files ending in “.inp” to open in python-mode
;; (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.inp\\'" . python-mode))
     (add-to-list 'load-path
              "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/")
      (autoload 'abaqus-mode "abaqus" "Enter abaqus mode." t)
      (setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.inp\\'" . abaqus-mode) auto-mode-alist))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; PDF-LATEX+INKSCAPE
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(LaTeX-command-style (quote (("" "%(PDF)%(latex) -shell-escape %S%(PDFout)"))))
 '(ansys-current-ansys-version "140")
 '(jabber-account-list (quote (("myemail.com"))))
 '(org-agenda-files (quote ("~/org/NOTES.org")))
 '(send-mail-function (quote smtpmail-send-it))
 '(smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.googlemail.com")
 '(smtpmail-smtp-service 587))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

;; ;;;;;;;;;;;
;; ;;GNUPLOT
;; ;;;;;;;;;;;

;; (add-to-list 'Info-default-directory-list "/usr/info")

;; ;; load the file
;; (require 'gnuplot)

;; ;; specify the gnuplot executable (if other than /usr/bin/gnuplot)
;; (setq gnuplot-program "/usr/bin/gnuplot")

;; ;; automatically open files ending with .gp or .gnuplot in gnuplot mode
;; (setq auto-mode-alist 
;; (append '(("\\.\\(gp\\|gnuplot\\|p\\)$" . gnuplot-mode)) auto-mode-alist))

; GIT controls
 (add-to-list 'load-path ".../git/contrib/emacs")
  (require 'git)
  (require 'git-blame)
  (require 'vc-git)

;; OCTAVE
(autoload 'run-octave "octave-inf" nil t)

(put 'upcase-region 'disabled nil)

;; PHP
(autoload 'php-mode "php-mode" "Major mode for editing php code." t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php$" . php-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.inc$" . php-mode))

;; Command for automatic alignment of comments
(defun align-comment (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (align-regexp beg end (concat "\\(\\s-*\\)" comment-start))
)
(global-set-key "\C-c\C-a" 'align-comment )

;; Flyspell mode binding to F6 key
(global-set-key [f6] 'flyspell-mode)        ; F6

;; Command for automatic auto-fill
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention. Obviously I have no a-m package being called from the init file. In fact, even without the init file it gives me the same error.

Comment: What is in the file being loaded?

Comment: Hi, I've just added the init file to the post. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not the file being loaded, which is `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/default.el`.  This is being loaded because you've put `usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp` in `load-path` (several times) and it presumably has bogons on it.

Comment: hey, here a couple of tricks to debug your init file next time: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/User%27s_Initialization_File#Debugging_the_Init_file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I didn't read the new ansys-mode https://github.com/dieter-wilhelm/ansys-mode documentation properly. Here is the issue:

> Please have a look at the accompanying `default.el’ customisation example. It can be used as a configuration file (after moving it e. g. to`/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp’ or `c:\EMACS_INSTALLDIR\site-lisp’, hint: The directory site-lisp/ in the Emacs installation tree is in its default load-path). Yet`default.el’ is loaded AFTER your personal Emacs configuration file (if there is any) `~/.emacs’ (or`~/.emacs.d/init.el’)! If you intend to change the following settings with Emacs’ customisation system or changing them directly in your personal configuration file, you must either set the variable `inhibit-default-init’ to`t’ “(setq inhibit-default-init t)” in your personal configuration file or remove `default.el’ otherwise your settings might be overwritten!

So I just added     `(setq inhibit-default-init t)` to the init file.

Thanks again!

Comment: If your answer answers the question, please accept it.

Comment: Hello Andre, please install this mode (now called apdl-mode) from Melpa, then there wont be any hassle with the configuration.

Comment: Thanks Dieter. I've installed it and it seems to offer a considerable amount of improvements in comparison to ansys-mode. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Note that with Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), the scripts in `contrib/emacs/` have outlived their usefulness and have been replaced with a stub that errors out and tells the user there are replacements.

So the `init` error message might not apply anymore in 2018.

See [commit 6d5ed48](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d5ed4836db94c07498e34ddebc31abbe532c8e1) (11 Apr 2018) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7d7d051](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d7d051c5e2b9f70adfe5538bd9ccbf60f35d4be), 08 May 2018)</sup>

> ### `git{,-blame}.el`: remove old bitrotting Emacs code
>
> The `git-blame.el` mode has been superseded by [Emacs's own
>   `vc-annotate`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VersionControl)
>   (invoked by <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd>).
>   Users of the `git.el` mode are now much better off using either Magit or the Git backend for Emacs's own VC mode.
>
> These modes were added over 10 years ago when Emacs's own Git support
>   was much less mature, and there weren't other mature modes in the wild
>   or shipped with Emacs itself.
>
> These days these modes have few if any users, and users of git aren't
>   well served by us shipping these (some OS's install them alongside git
>   by default, which is confusing and leads users astray).
>
> [...] rather than receive a cryptic load error when they upgrade,
>   existing users will get an error directing them to the `README` file, or
>   to just stop requiring these modes

See "[`git/contrib/emacs/README`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ccdcbd54c4475c2238b310f7113ab3075b5abc9c/contrib/emacs/README)" for more.